# Include non-ARC library in an ARC app?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

So, is it possible?

I get this error multiple times:

```
ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions
```

For example here:

```
typedef struct {
    BOOL _field1;
    union {
        struct {
            id _field1;
            id _field2;
        } _field1;
        GSEventRef _field2;
    } _field2;
} XXStruct_CKAdxD;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to add `-fno-objc-arc` to the compiler options for each file that doesn't / can't use ARC. Within Xcode you do this from the 'Compile Sources' build phase of your target. Double click the file and add `-fno-objc-arc` to the box that pops up.

Comment: But I only have the headers and not the source of the framework

Comment: OK I see what you mean then. I think in that case you're not going to be able to use ARC in your code that interfaces with this library since the struct definition can't have an object in it (the `id _field1`, `id _field2`). I'll do some hunting though as I've not come across this much before.

Comment: Nevermind. I just wrapped the code that needed the framework in a non-ARC class and set the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to the compiler. Then I called the class methods from inside the ARC code. Seems to work fine!

Comment: Yeh that would be the workaround I would go for to be honest. Glad you solved it.

Comment: @mattjgalloway so u mean you copy pasted the classes needed separately, and not inside the .framework, right? and then add the flag?