# xcode build failed no explanation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My project has weirdly started failing with no error messages. Ive tried cleaning the project and this had no effect. I know this is all a bit vague but i havent done anything to revert or undo. its just randomly started to happen. Can anyone suggest a way of debugging what the problem is?

Phil

Comment: Simulator build or Device build or does that not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the derived data (Organizer->Projects / cmd + shift + 2) and then cleaning (cmd+shift+K)?

Maybe closing xCode and rebooting?

I've had it a few times and this worked for me sometimes.

Comment: hi thomas, thanks no one replied so i dug out an older version of the project and redone some stuff. I tried cleaning but didnt try the derived data. I did try restarting but that didnt help.

Comment: This will also help if Xcode messes the syntax highlighting again.

Comment: A quick fix for syntax highlighting is also changing the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you're using non-arc code in arc project, make sure you added "-fno-objc-arc" flags to .m files. [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970503/2225302)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to re-clone my git repository to see what the build issue actually was.  In my case the build issue was related to a dev provisioning profile that was no longer valid.  I was able to correct this easily and the build properly.