# Objective-C and ARC? Use or not to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

when reading one of the iOS 5 book I've came across such information:

> "While ARC makes it easier for you to write applications without
>   worrying about object management, lot of third-party libraries still
>   need to manually release objects. For this book, all the projects are
>   created with ARC turned off (...)" .

I am new to iOS Development, and I am not sure how to interpret it. Understanding Memory Management for iOS seems to be quite (very) important thing, but should I understood, that ARC is just a nice feature and I have to start without learning it, because it so new it can be not supported or possible to use in many situations?

Comment: I'm asking mainly because this was mentioned in the iOS 5 Development book.

Comment: Sorry, you are certainly right. I am new here and some I make such mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a personal choice.

If you use ARC, you are not bothered about memory management.

But if you know how to make a full-fledged app with MRC (Manual Retain count) then using ARC is not bad.

Even in ARC at some specific time, you need to allocate and release memory, therefore MRC must to be learnt.

Answer (score 12):

Do yourself a favor, use ARC. This is by far the best addition to the language that has happened in the last five years. It lets you deal with memory management in a more *declarative*, rather than a *procedural* way, freeing you from writing a lot of "boilerplate code".

This is not to say that learning about manual memory management is unimportant: you should definitely know how it works, and be able to read the code written without ARC. But as far as your newly developed code is concerned, you should stay with ARC, because manual memory management wastes a lot of your development effort for nothing.

Better yet, get yourself another book: it appears that the authors did not have enough time to rework the examples for ARC, so they inserted a rather lame excuse about "other libraries out there".

Comment: Great one about the book! Totally agree

Answer (score 1):

I still prefere to create non ARC projects.

But some weeks ago i have written this great article http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1  and sounds like this is great feature that Apple provides.

So, i want to try it. Lots of my college already use ARC and i see it works good.

But, one thing that i want to say - ARC isn't mean that you must write code and don't worry about memory management. ARC - this is something else, ARC also has own memory management rules/laws that you must keep in your mind while writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are new to objective C, the best thing you can do is to use ARC in your project. ARC is stable, and make memory management quite easier.

The books was right that there are some 3rd party libraries that still follows Manual memory management. But most of these libraries now provide ARC version also. If not [you can still use them in your ARC project](http://www.exactmagic.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/), by adding it as a static library project. Also you can [disable ARC per specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969634/include-non-arc-library-in-an-arc-app) too.

I started iOS development in the pre ARC days, and to me manual memory management was difficult at first. So for starters, with ARC around, definitely ARC. Try to understand manual memory management when you have spare time.

Disclaimer : I still do not use ARC much, but for starters, ARC is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

ARC is nice to use, as a beginner it is very helpful. When we include third party libraries, you can have a option to disable ARC for that particular file (or) library.

For disabling ARC for a particular file:

add **-fno-objc-arc** to the compiler flags for the files you don't want ARC. In Xcode 4, you can do this under your target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

If you want to understand Memory Management from the beginning, disable ARC and try yourself. That may help you alot

Answer (score 1):

> ARC is one of the best feature provided by Apple.
>
> ARC takes care of overhead related to **memory management issues**
>   also Apple recommends use of ARC.
>
> Rather than not using it better to make **best** use of it and stay free of memory overhead
>
> I would suggest you to make use of ARC  but do study how memory is
>   managed by ARC under the hood.
>
> But when you need to develop applications with **deployment target below**
>   ***ios 4.0***  You need to **manually retain-release memory**.